# Encoding problems at the end of the execution

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding, beautifulsoup

I've an encoding problem with my script. This is my script :

```
def parse_airfields():
    html = urlopen('https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/aip/enligne/FRANCE/AIRAC-2015-09-17/html/eAIP/FR-AD-1.3-fr-FR.html').read()
    html = html.decode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    
    # A lot of work [....]

    return airfields


if __name__ == '__main__':
    airfields = parse_airfields()

    for airfield in airfields:
        for value in airfield.values():
            if isinstance(value, str):
                value.encode('utf-8')

    with open('airfields.json', 'w') as airfields_file:
        json.dump(airfields, airfields_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

I tried without `encode()` and without `decode()` but I have the same résult... An encoding problem in my JSON file:
[image: encoding problem with my json]

Why ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What problem? Also, that line that calls the `encode()` method disposes of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.encode` and `bytes.decode` don't modify the value in place; you're not assigning the return value of `value.encode('utf-8')` so you haven't actually changed anything. Of course, I don't think you really want to; the `json` module works with text (`str`), not binary data (`bytes`).

The problem is that strict JSON usually doesn't include non-ASCII characters in its strings; it uses the escapes, e.g. `\u00b0`. Python will output the `utf-8` directly if you tell it to though, just add `ensure_ascii=False` to the arguments of your `json.dump(...)` call.

Comment: Wow! That's perfect! Thanks for your explaination. Have a nice day.